# How to remove the transparency of the terminal background?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, terminal

I have set up my Raspberry Pi 3, but the terminal has a completely transparent background. This means I can see the desktop which is very distracting.

I've been trying `setterm --background black` but nothing happens.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the options tabs select *Edit* -> *Preferences* -> "*Style*" tab -> *background* -> use the "*Opacity*" slider -> "*OK*" -> and *OK* again.

Comment: Ah my eyes! I can see again!

Comment: on the official raspberry touch the screen resolution seems to be to low for the second ok button to be visible. Even if increasing the resolution to 1024x618 this happens. I'll try with an external hdmi connection.

Answer (score -1):

@Gabboxl is right but you need to make sure you can hit the ok buttons. I finally managed to do this via an ssh connection

```
ssh pidevice lxterminal&
```

[image: Background Opacity]
[image: Style Dialog]